# Remove last two path components of a path in a shell variable

Tags: shell, variables, replace

I have a variable `var=/usr/local/bin/test/exec`

Now i have to remove last 2 path components in the above variable say:

```
var=/usr/local/bin/
```

After removing the last 2 strings I have to use this variable 'var' in a shell loop.

I tried:

```
  var='/usr/local/bin/test/exec'
  echo ${var#$(dirname "$(dirname "$s")")/}
```

Output:

```
test/exec
```

I am getting the truncated part as output, but I was expecting the rest of the part, not the truncated part.

Comment: var1="$(echo $var | sed 's/.\{9\}$//')"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK after some googling i have found the solution for this:

```
var1="$(echo $var | cut -d '/' -f-4)"
```

Comment: var1="$(echo $var | sed 's/.\{9\}$//')"

Answer (score 2):

You may be interested in the shell's internal substring processing operators: `%`, `%%`, `#` and`##`. Observe:

```
#!/bin/sh

var=/usr/local/bin/test/exec

# use shell substring processing to cut the variable down to size:

var="${var%/*}"
var="${var%/*}"

echo "$var" 

# Manipulate the resulting string in a loop
for i in 1 2 3
do echo "${var}${i}"
done
```

Comment: I think he wants the parts you chopped off, but if you add another var with the original and then clip the remainder it should work: `var2=/usr/local/bin/test/exec; var=$(sed "s#${var}##" <<< $var2)`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know the field count, there is a standard `awk` solution.  However, I'll show another trick using `rev`

```
var='/usr/local/bin/test/exec'; echo $var | rev | cut -d/ -f3- | rev
```

will give

```
/usr/local/bin
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this method also

```
var=/usr/local/bin/test/exec

sed 's_\(.*\)/.*/.*$_\1_' <<< $var
```

Another Method

```
sed 's_\(.*\)\(/.*\)\{2\}$_\1_' <<< $var
```

**Output:**

```
/usr/local/bin
```